# form validated but there are wrong input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable the button as long as the one of any value is invalid.
but what is happening here is it matter not how many wrong values u have as long as one last input is right, the button became enabled.

for example, i have 2 prior wrong inputs and button is disabled. and then i enter valid value next and the button became enabled despite having 2 wrong inputs above.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/48ta6kjw/4/
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="value1" > 
<span id="valid1"></span> <br>

<input type="text" id="value2">
<span id="valid2"></span><br>

<input type="text" id="value3">
<span id="valid3"></span><br>

<button id="btn">
button
</button>
```

css

```
input,button{
  margin:2px;
}
```

jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkValue1();
  checkValue2();
  checkValue3();
});

function checkValue1(){
$('#value1').blur(function(){
    var v1=$(this).val();
  if((v1.length)>5){
  $('#valid1').html("valid");
  $("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
   $('#valid1').html("invalid");
   $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
}
function checkValue2(){
$('#value2').blur(function(){
    var v2=$(this).val();
  if((v2.length)>5){
  $('#valid2').html("valid");
  $("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
   $('#valid2').html("invalid");
   $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
}
function checkValue3(){
$('#value3').blur(function(){
    var v3=$(this).val();
  if((v3.length)>5){
  $('#valid3').html("valid");
  $("#btn").prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
   $('#valid3').html("invalid");
   $("#btn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

**#1** Code like this gets unmaintable **very** quickly! Imagine you add 2, 5 or 10 more fields, do you want to write 10 additional *check1 - 10* functions ?

**#2** You attach event handlers in your functions and call these function on `docment.ready`. That is redundant. You can directly use the code from within the functions in the document ready function and use them without the extra step of wrapping and calling them.

**#3** You have multiple fields in your form, that all have requirements to make your condidtion - `enable button` -  true or false. But you only check **one** of theses conditions in your functions. That means that *any time* a user fills in an input and that input is valid, the button gets enabled, regardless of the validity of the other input fields.

**#4** I highly suggest, you look into and use available solutions like the jQuery Validation Plugin.

A possible solution for your code could look like this:

```js
// for all input fields with the data-min attribute, check on blur if they are valid
$('input[data-min]').on('blur', function() {
  // get the current length of the input element, ALWAYS trim the value to get rid of whitespaces
  let currentLength = $(this).val().trim().length;
  // get the min length from the data attribute
  let minLength = $(this).data('min');
  // toogle the class `invalid` on the element
  $(this).toggleClass("invalid", (currentLength < minLength));
  // toogle the class `valid` on the element
  $(this).toggleClass("valid", (currentLength >= minLength));
  // get the form element that this input is part of
  let $form = $(this).closest('form');
  // check if the form is valid
  isValid( $form );
});


function isValid( $form ) {
// the form is only valid if all input fields have the class "valid"
    $('#btn').prop('disabled', $form.find('input.valid').length <  $form.find('input').length);
}
```

```css
input,button{
  margin:2px;
}   

input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" data-min="6">
  <input type="text" data-min="6" >
  <input type="text check-length" data-min="6">

  <button id="btn" disabled="true">
    button
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Disagree with point #2 - that's a matter of style - yes you can inline anon functions, but it's also good practice to move them to separate functions where they can have meaning names and be called without having ugly work-arounds such as `$("#input").blur()`  (gave a +1 regardless, it's only a style issue)

Comment: Totally agree with (unnumbered) point #4 - use a plugin :)

Comment: You are right, I guess it should rather be a critique to the point that his code is not DRY. Which is more or less mentioned in #1.